# react child component doesn't render updated prop value

Tags: reactjs

Here I am trying to render my tasks' titles in a list. But for some reason they don't render. Here is the `MyTasks` component:

```
const MyTasks = (props) => {
  const tasks = [...props.tasks];
  console.log(props.tasks, "props.tasks");
  console.log(tasks, "tasks");
  console.log(tasks[0], "tasks[0]");
  return (
    <ListGroup className="mx-2 mt-4">
      {tasks.map((task) => {
        return <ListGroup.Item key={task.id}>{task.title}</ListGroup.Item>;
      })}
    </ListGroup>
  );
};

export default MyTasks;
```

I tried `console.log` inside the component but for some reason I can't access the array elements but I can view the `props.tasks` array.

In my `TaskLists` component I am rendering the `MyTasks` component.

`TaskLists` component is using a useState hook for updating the `tasks` prop value of the `MyTasks` component but during the child component re-render I am not able to access the elements in the `props.tasks` array.

```
const TaskList = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  const getTasks = () => {
  //code to get tasks data from data base
  setTasks(taskList);
};
  useEffect(() => {
    getTasks();  
  })
  return (
    <ListGroup className="mx-2 mt-4">
      <MyTasks tasks={tasks} />
    </ListGroup>
  );
};
```

[Here is my `console.log` screenshot, I cant access the array elements for some reason.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EBOV.png)

Comment: @FlorianWalch But when I did `console.log(props.tasks)` the array already has 2 elements

Comment: Nvm, I think I saw sth else in the screenshot

Comment: Try to modify this `setTasks(taskList);` to this `setTasks(tasks);`

Comment: Why do you need to shallow clone the tasks array in `MyTasks`? Why can't you just use `props.tasks`?

Comment: @nuser137 I don't understand, `taskList` is the array we get from the data base so I am updating the state by `setTasks(taskList)`

Answer (score 0):

`getTasks` function is only decleared but never invoked.

You might want to invoke it in a useEffect hook with empty braces so it would happen only once at startup.

```
useEffect(() => {
   getTasks();
}, []);
```

Comment: I did not include the complete code for TaskList, but I have a useEffect and I have invoked `getTasks()`

Comment: @ash54321 I think you  forgot `[]` to use in your `useEffect` as mentioned in @Erez's answer.

Comment: @nuser137 no actually there are a lot of dependencies I just didn't put them in here. But as you can see from the `console.log(props.tasks)` the data was retrieved and forwarded to the child component but I am unable iterate on the array

Comment: @ash54321 can you try `({ tasks }) ` instead of `(props)` in MyTasks component?

Comment: @myrn isn't `props.tasks ` the same as destructuring `tasks` from the `props` object